# Expected a module name after module import

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

My project use cocoa pods to manager code dependency, and I create a private repo to manage my team code. 
Recently, we decide to using `Swift` as our developing language mixed with `Objective-C`.
When I importing a module of my private repo which written by `Objective-C` to my Swift code, I got this error `"Expected a module name after module import"` in line of `@import ModuleName;` at bridge file `ProjectName-Swift.h` which auto generated by xCode?

Any idea how to solve this error?

Comment: You could try the system-style import: #import <ModuleName/Filename.h>

Comment: `@import ModuleName;`  is xCode generated code, I cant edit it.

Comment: @Moonwalkr change to #import <ModuleName/Filename.h>, it worked. But I want to know why? I can use other framework like AFNetworking well. And  because ProjectName-Swift.h generated by xCode , I need to update it after build clean.

Comment: I'm not sure why. I've just seen this issue before, i.e. https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3426